# I need users of a list when creating a new entry to be asked to upload a picture from their desktop and have it linked with their entry

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-form

I have been trying through several version of SharePoint to create a User entered list that would go through different columns of data entry and dates and text with great success.  Where I get stuck now with SharePoint Online is when I want the users to upload a picture from their desktop of the before condition and the after condition.  The pictures are on their desktop not on a website.

I have tried using the column setup to be an "Image" Type  - but the input is just a line with no upload features.  Using the  "Hyperlink or Picture" is successful if the picture has an URL and I set it to display Picture.  My problem is that we do not have a website that I can have everyone store their pictures. and even if I did they would have to upload them - look up the URL - paste it into the LIST  and do this successfully.

I thought about setting up a picture library in our SharePoint but you still have to get the full URL and use the Hyperlink - but this usually throws a too many character error (our sharepoint names and structure have so many characters that it exceeds the 255 characters that can be entered in the URL field with the picture names)

What I want if possible is just a way to have a user upload a picture within the custom list for a Before Picture and an After Picture from their desktop to show up and be attached to the site documents or library.  Using whichever type works in that way or can have some added intelligence.

I tried Julie's answer but it still does not allow adding with the Image field - it just gives me a blank box for text.

It appears I am in a Teams site in the classic Experience.

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint online modern experience, add an image column and upload the picture from desktop, it will shown the image instead of just a line:

[image]

Then format the column as shown below, when you double click the picture, it will open the related file:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "img",
  "attributes": {
    "src": "@currentField.serverRelativeUrl",
    "alt": "@currentField.fileName"
  },
  "style": {
    "width": "100%",
    "max-width": "100%"
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey Julie - It is in a Teams site so not in the Modern experience

Comment: Even if you are using classic team site, you can still user modern experience, since the Image column is a modern column.please go to library settings> Advanced settings> scroll down to the button and select New experience for the library.Then you could use it correctly.